# Why is the unit test coverage for GO not covering logs and fmt statements

Tags: unit-testing, go, code-coverage

I have been writing unit tests for a card functionality which i built out in GO, and am trying to check the test coverage, and when its generated i see that lines like `fmt.Println("binary write failed: ", err)` are marked as red, which means they are not tracked as part of the unit test implementation.

Is there a way to get them included in the unit tests to enable them to be covered?
[image]

Comment: It is not included, because that line never ran. To run that line, you have to make `binary.Write` return error, which is difficult to do. Trying to cover each and every line is not a useful testing strategy.

Comment: Post code as text. Don't post images of code.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to ensure full test coverage, then you'll probably need to do something a little strange, like:

```
package whatever

var BinaryWrite = binary.Write

func Buffs(val1, val2 uint8) ([]byte, error) {
    // ...
    err = BinaryWrite(buf, binary.LittleEndian, a)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("binary write failed: %w", err)
    }
}
```

and then in your test you can do:

```
func TestBuffs(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("test failure", func(t *testing.T) {
        orig := BinaryWrite
        defer func() {
            BinaryWrite = orig
        }()
        BinaryWrite = func( /* whatever */ ) error {
            return errors.New("whoops")
        }
        _, err := Buff(1, 2)
        if err == nil {
            t.Fail("it should return an error")
        } else {
            if err.Error() != "binary write failed: whoops" {
                t.Fail("it should wrap the binary write error")
            }
        }
```